# Angular 2 reactive form custom validation

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have 4 form fields and i want to check whether the 'oldpass' and 'newpass' fields are same using reactive form.

```
this.changePasswordForm = fb.group({
     'oldpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
     'newpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
     'confirmpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
     'otp': ['']
   },{validator: CustomValidator.matchConfirmFields('newpass', 'confirmpass')});
```

And i am able to validate the 'newpass' and 'confirmpass' fields using the following code.

```
static matchConfirmFields(pass: string, confirmpass: string) {
      return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
        let spass = group.controls[pass];
        let sconfirmpass = group.controls[confirmpass];

        if (spass.value !== sconfirmpass.value) {
          return {
            mismatchedPasswords: true
          };
        }
      }
    }
```

**How do i validate 'oldpass' and 'newpass' fields similar way.**

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2 check this out first

Comment: thanks misha..but how do i call second validator for 'oldpass' and 'newpass'. can u please help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer changes the way the validators in your FormGroup.
First we'll add a new validator function **to your class**.
It only compares an abstract control to a string, nothing special
There is an option for equal or is not equal.

```
 public confirmPasswordValidator(control: AbstractControl, compareValue: string, equal: boolean = true): null | {} {
    if ((control.value === compareValue) === equal) {
      return null;
    }
    return {
      confirmPassword: {
        valid: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Now in the FormGroup we add it to the Controls we want to add it to all controls that use it and signify what to do with it.

```
this.changePasswordForm = fb.group({
  'oldpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
  'newpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6),
  (control) => this.confirmPasswordValidator(control, this.changePasswordForm ? this.changePasswordForm.controls['oldpass'].value : '', false)])],
  'confirmpass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,
  (control) => this.confirmPasswordValidator(control, this.changePasswordForm ? this.changePasswordForm.controls['newpass'].value : '')
  ])],
  'otp': ['']
});
```

Comment: @vishnu if I did misunderstand your question, feel free to tell me and I'll delete this